# why bootstrap uses floats on .span instead of display: inline-block?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, css-float, css

I was tinkering with custom **grid** and wanted to see how other people have created their grid-systems. Since twitter's **bootstrap** seemed to be so popular i've looked at its code. Now i wonder **why are they using floats?** I would use `display: inline-block;` html elements have either `display: inline;` or `display: block;` i would try to avoid floats. But for some reason bootstrap creators decided to use floats. first i was thinking they used them to have backward compatibility since ie6 does not support `display: inline-block;` and ie7 supports it only on elements with `display: inline;` by default. But ie6 more or less out of the game and since they use [micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) which uses *zoom: 1; to target **ie6+** IMO they could replicate the same `display: inline-block;` with `*display: inline; *zoom: 1;` So the final Question **Why Floats Over Display Inline Block?** Are there any issues they tried to solve i didn't mentioned above?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In the term of semantic web, the `display: inline-block` should be used when we want to place a block level element like `<img>` within line(s) of text. We shouldn't use inline placement for making the pages main layout. The element with `display: inline-block` also takes effect from properties like `font-size` and `line-height` of parent element. This will decrease the accuracy of page layout.
You would better get in the habit of using `float` instead of `inline-block` when making the page main layout.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you sure meant img is an inline element and p is a block level element and not vice versa, don't you?:)

Comment: Actually, both `img` and `p` are block level elements. I corrected the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake it not inline level element but also not block level element. **img** tags are **inline-block** by default. You can define width and height like by block level elements but it also can flow inline with other elements on the same line without being floated.

Comment: "The element with display: inline-block also takes effect from properties like font-size and line-height of parent element." - Elements always "take affect" from their parents unless overridden.. I've used inline-block for layout purposes for like 2 years without any problem. IE7 renders inline-block if you conditionally set it to inline for IE7. It basically removes the need for .clearfix also. I'm yet to find any downside using it!

Comment: In terms of semantic web, CSS like `inline-block` or `float` does not affect semantics.

Answer (score 16):

Inline blocks are white-space aware, have an auto width of the actual content and stacks in the order they have in HTML. Floats aren't but require a clearfix method and are based on block elements. These elements have auto width on the available space horizontally. Purely semantically, inline-blocks are less semantic since the white-space aware format and importance of order. But looking at it purely in a functional way, both just aren't made for a grid. And if it wasn't for pseudo CSS, we would have un-semantic HTML tag clearfixe's as well. So in my believes they are both not winners. But there is no alternative for the time being when flexbox will become mandatory in upcoming years.

With inline blocks:

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:30%;">col1
    </div><div style="display:inline-block; width:70%;">col2</div>
</div>
```

Tags must be glued together/appended, to dismiss any gutter. The container div is necessary to force the items being part of a separate row.

With floats:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div style="float:left; width:30%;">col1</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:70%;">col2</div>
</div>
```

Clearfix is necessary to force a "row" (dismiss any normal flow items issues or floats after the floats)

Whether use one or the other is a matter of your goal (and taste). I must say I like inline-blocks more than floats, as long as you know the both of the col widths or use relative sizing (%). I thinks it's more intuitive and predictable than floats with clearfix, a fix" for issues that aren't even issues if it was used by how it should be used. Only the white-space awareness of inline blocks force you to use some funky html, that's a downside.

Ironically, tables do exactly all this (and even col-heights and vertically alignement's) without any issues. Since inline-blocks have to be placed in order, there's an motive for discussing here.

If we are talking about responsive, table 'loses' of inline-blocks. Let say you have 4 cols on a desktop and you want 2 cols on a tablet and 1 on a mobile. With inline blocks, you 'just' give the cols other width dimensions and they hopefully wrap nice (be aware of margins as they collapse). With tables, you're bound to actual rows, which can be quite stubborn. Flexbox is needed for a long time and looks beautiful. You can adjust the layout flexible on certain circumstances.

Bootstrap can be handy to learn how they did something. Just read in 3.0 they are using relative grid sizing. Which gives an issue with nested grids and aligning.

```
----  --a-  ----  ----
---b------
....  ..c.
```

Col a is a normal parent col. Col c is a child nested col of b. It's hard to align c with a with relative sizing since the gutter is variable to the container, unless you're using padding and border-box model. But that way you lose a lot of flexibility. When you want the col to have some background and padding, you're messing up the grid system, so you have to use container which you style, which would clutter the code. I haven't studied if they found a solution to this. I haven't yet. I went to fixed pixels, but that means in responsive design you can only have a few fixed width's and for everything around mobile use a relative grid.

Comment: great answer! as i asked first i wasn't aware of the white space sensitivity of the inline-block level elements and just like you i like to use inline-block more than float. I like the idea of the flexbox too but i think we are not there yet and browser vendors will take their time to implement it properly although webkit devs make a good job...

Comment: Yeah exactly, probably takes years since IE8 will be around some time, or someone writes an htc unit for it. As today IE10 has support for an old flexbox syntax which is deprecated already. So yeah, we're currently stuck to floats/inline-blocks or tables ;)

Comment: This is a way better answer than the one marked as the answer.  It actually has a real reason for why inline-block isn't used.  It's an unfortunate reason, but it has a point.  The other answer was a theoretical and academic with a poke in the eye of "...because I said so." ending.  My only problem with using floats in this situation is they explicit turn off floating for input elements using spans, and so your floating spans jump ahead of all input fields leading to pain.

Comment: "it's easier with floats since the divs are block elements and occupy the available horizontal space" << This is not true, unless I'm misunderstanding something.  Take a look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46ahC/

Comment: Yeah sorry, this is indeed incorrect, I can't recall exactly why and what I meant with that but I removed the paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer grid systems that use `display: inline-block;` rather than `float`, such as [Pure](http://purecss.io/grids/) (formerly Yahoo YUI Grid), because they internationalise without extra styles; change the text direction to right-to-left and the layout automatically reverses; floats don't do this. Floats also introduce the need to *clear* and other cross browser oddities. Any inaccuracies that `inline-block` may have over `float` can be remedied, as demonstrated by Pure. As to the criticism that `display: inline-block;` is *not meant* to be used for layout, perhaps the use of `display: table;` should also be banned for cross-browser centring. I would also question whether the term *Semantic Web* really applies to CSS since the term is primarily concerned with HTML and using its elements and attributes to impart machine readable meaning; the whole point of CSS is to style semantic HTML as radically as one wants to, hence classic sites like *CSS Zen Garden*.

I say that as long as the technique is not exploiting a bug, is not obstructing content to users and devices and is sufficiently supported then it is acceptable. There is no reason that one can't use CSS in unorthodox, but supported, ways, just like Stu Nicholls' CSSPlay.

Interestingly, [Flexible Box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) is also incorporated into Pure grids, a superior layout system compatible with modern browsers (≥IE10 and equivalent browsers).