# Creating a centered table with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 20 icons and I want to make a centered horizontal line of images from them. But I can't use HTML table because I want it to be responsive. It should be wrapped for mobile users. By using HTML table I guess I should use 1 row and 20 columns, but it won't wrap for small screens.

I created a group of divs like this. The view of this is OK. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mayJ6/

```
<div style="display: inline-block; border: solid 1px black;">
    <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" >
        <img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/157940_262105851352_1630693163_q.jpg"
           width="50" height="50" alt="photo"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127150/why-bootstrap-uses-floats-on-span-instead-of-display-inline-block/14148240#14148240) tells not to use display inline block in this situation. Is there a better solution that looks similar, by using Twitter Bootstrap etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I think for this case `display: inline-block` is perfectly fine.

In the answer you reference they are talking about the main layout, like when you have 2 or 3 columns and want to display them side by side, in which case floating them is better.

You can achieve the same result with floats but you'll have to wrap the photos / icons with a container and set a fixed width or padding in order to center them like this. It will still wrap on smaller resolutions if you set the width in percentages like in my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/E9pS9/