# Why bootstrap uses floating elements to construct Grid System?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm interested in understanding the architectural decision that is not so obvious for me : my naive point of view is  if we are designing layout framework (javascript always aware)  we could construct it on floating elements or on inline-blocks (fixing their width). So why floating was chosen? What was so attractive in flaoting columns?

I just want to understand the bootstrap architecture better.

P.S. May be I do not see whole complexity of the constructing Grid System using inline blocks ... It seems what we need we can achieve the same easy:  standard width and offset css  for columns and rows.  Than manipulate window sizes on resize events with javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14547589/280143 this is the most convincing explanation I've seen.

Comment: What do you mean by javascript always aware, as far as I know, the grid system doesn't rely on bootstrap.js, only bootstrap.css.

Comment: When using percentages as sizes for responsive designs everything has to perfectly fit. Just the distance inline-block elements keeps between them is enough reason to never use it for grids